# How to use angular-translate within a customer filter and re-translate on $translate.use()

Tags: angular-translate

I'm using a custom filter to translate the `ng-options` of a select element. The translate works fine UNTIL I use `$translate.use()` to change the language. I want the `ng-options` to be re-translated. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is my customer filter:

```
function translateAndFormatPhoneCountry(translateFilter) {
    return function(phoneCountry) {
        return translateFilter(phoneCountry.name) + " (" + phoneCountry.countryCode + ")";
    };
}
```

And this is my select element:

`phoneCountry` will typically look like this:

```
{"name": "UNITED_KINGDOM", "countryCode": "+44"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, I got it sorted. See here for the guiding light: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/134.

In the template:

ng-options="signup.translate.instant(phoneCountry.name) for phoneCountry in signup.model.phoneCountries"

In the controller, inject $translate then:

this.translate = $translate;